# Disable caching on a route

Tags: routes, caching

I have a route with a parameter, e.g. `/r/{app_id}`. The controller extends `ContainerInjectionInterface`.  The method either returns a render array or a `new TrustedRedirectResponse`.

I believe I have a caching problem because subsequent visits to the page will not update even with changing `{app_id}`.  If I visit from another browser I get the correct response one time.

My controller is, basically, this:

```
if (!$a) {
  return ['#markup' => 'no'];
}

return new TrustedRedirectResponse($url);
```

I have tried to disable cache in several ways, to no avail:

- `addCacheableDependency`
- putting `#cache => ['max-age' => 0]` on the render array
- `\Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger();`
- using `$response = new Response()` and `$response->setCache(['max_age' => 0])` and then, from within the conditional, using `$response->setContent('blah')`

Not having luck with any of the above.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to do all together, set cache max-age = 0 for all responses the controller returns and apply the kill switch

```
public function mycontroller() {

  \Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger();

  if (!$a) {
    return [
      '#markup' => 'no',
      '#cache' => ['max-age' => 0],
    ];
  }

  return (new TrustedRedirectResponse($url))
    ->addCacheableDependency((new CacheableMetadata())->setCacheMaxAge(0));
}
```

and then clear the cache one more time.

Comment: The return code has a syntax error. Dont know how this worked for you. Although the answer below plus the "\Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger();" line solved the issue for me

Comment: @ventura, you can't just copy-and-paste this return statement. You only need this code in the context of the question.

Comment: Fair enough. Regardless, I thought my comment might help someone :) No offence intended

Answer (score 12):

You can also disable caching via the route under the `options` key like this, `no_cache: 'TRUE'`.  Here is a full example of a route:

```
my_awesome_module.do
  path: '/do-awesome'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\my_awesome_module\Controller\MyAwesomeModuleController::doAwesome'
  options:
    no_cache: 'TRUE'
```

Comment: Works only if your route doesn't require a TrustedRedirectResponse

Comment: @ChristopheCARON could you give a bit more information on this? I tested it with a TrustedRedirectResponse and seems to do the job.

Comment: This seems like the best (and simplest) answer. My controller is redirecting based on the site language and using TrustedRedirectResponse to an external URL. The no_cache option works well.