# Request does not reach controller after a few requests

Tags: caching, 9

I have a custom module for an online shop. Module's controller gets a product id which is sent by the user through a query string and puts it into the session. That is crucial for the shopping cart functionality.

Things are that, after clearing the cache, everything is ok, but after a few minutes/requests, the requests stop entering the controller. It seems like the response has been cached, even if:

- I have disabled the caches at admin/config/development/performance,
- I return '#cache' => ['max-age => 0] within the render array returned by the controller and
- all responses come with the header "x-drupal-cache-max-age: 0 (Uncacheable)".

I also noticed that these errors usually come with the following apache error:

```
AH01070: Error parsing script headers
```

Comment: The error is probably only because you are trying to debug caching by enabling `http.response.debug_cacheability_header`. Otherwise this might be helpful https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/230169/disable-caching-on-a-route

Comment: I think max-age => 0 doesn’t bubble properly in all cases without a patch. You can use query strings as cache contexts for better performance.

Comment: @cilefen you are right. If you want to disable cache on a controller you need to use this method:
  public function getCacheMaxAge(): int {
    return 0;
  }

Comment: @4uk4 This was my problem! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable the caching of a controller, use this method in your controller class:

```
  /**
   * @return int
   */
  public function getCacheMaxAge(): int {
    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Good to know, thanks.

Comment: Not necessary when you already return cache max-age in the render array and also it has no effect because a controller doesn't implement this method.